# How to change height/width of organization browser?

Tags: organization-browser

Changing the height of the organization browser web part seems to always revert back to the same fixed height.

How to customize the organization chart / browser on page to show a different height and width in order to show more profiles at once? (to show more profiles on page by default especially vertically).

Answer (score 1):

Even if this question is almost 2 years old - I recently faced the same problem and thought I would share a solution:

Open the site page (default.aspx or homepage.aspx) in SharePoint Designer. Find the content placeholder which hosts your profile browser web part.

Check, if there is already a style block for this placeholder, otherwise add a new one:

```
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
```

Inside the style block add the following css definition:

```
#ctl00_ctl43_g_84cdca9f_78ab_4c02_9ea6_94421c8f8f8b {
height:[your height]!important;
}
```

Don't know, if the ID is the same in your case. You can check the ID of the 'div' tag by using the F12 tools in IE.

Now you can change the height of your web part via 'Edit Page' => 'Edit Web Part' to [your height].